# Tail multiple files shown by separate colors?

Tags: bash, logging

I follow multiple log files like this:

```
tail -f /var/log/apache2/tv7r9r3falz0_error.log protected/runtime/application.log
```

Is there a way to color each file so I don't have to rely on finding the headers:

```
==> protected/runtime/application.log <==
```

I know about `multitail`, but I want to freely scroll.

Comment: You could try piping the output through `awk` and switch colors based on the header lines as you see them. If I had more time at the moment I'd try to write something up as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will print the output in two different colors depending on which log file it comes from:

```
tail -f log1 log2 | awk $'/==> log1/{print "\033[0m\033[1;33;40m";} /==> log2/{print "\033[0m\033[1;35;40m";} 1'
```

*Update by Elliot Chance*: Thats the start I needed, here was the working version:

```
tail -f /var/log/apache2/tv7r9r3falz0_error.log protected/runtime/application.log | awk '/==> /{print "\033[0m\033[1;36;40m";} /==> p/{print "\033[0m\033[1;33;40m";} {print $0}'
```